# Who is this sexual fantasy of Wolverine?

Tags: marvel, comics, x-men, character-identification, wolverine

I stumbled upon a YouTube video about weird marvel sexual encounters:

Where he shows a panel where Emma Frost discovers Wolverine sexual fantasies:
[image]

Correct me if I am wrong left to right these women are:

[Mystique](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mystique_(comics)), [Emma Frost](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Emma_Frost), [Squirrel Girl](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Squirrel_Girl), ???????? and [Jewel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jessica_Jones#Early_years)

I want to know who is the remaining multi-handed girl?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I believe that might be [Spiral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spiral_%28comics%29)

[image]

Comment: Mentioned here; http://whatculture.com/comics/12-essential-r-rated-wolverine-moments?page=11

Comment: Multiple arms seems to confirm it.

Comment: Never even heard about this character before

Comment: @Valorum thanks for the source, I feel no need to wait for more answer as it seems right only but now I wonder did spiral and Wolverine are a thing?

Comment: She should be familiar to anyone who played the *X-Men:  Children of the Atom* fighting game by Capcom.

Comment: I'm just surprised no one is commenting on the fact that Squirrel-Girl is part of Logan's sexual fantasy